# Should I create SYNC jobs only in SQLake?

Tags: upsolver, sqlake

Should we always be just creating sync jobs as our general rule of thumb in Upsolver SQLake?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, yes, you want to use sync jobs.The only case that you don't want to use sync job is when you have an input to table that you don't want to wait.
Example: you have 5 jobs that write to a table and some jobs that read from that table. If you don't want the entire pipeline to stuck if one of the 5 jobs is stuck, then your pipeline needs to be unsync (or at least this specific job that you think it may stuck to be unsync)

Note: unsync is not a keyword. If create JOB  by default creates unsync job. CREATE SYNC job  creates SYNC job.